# Why does my jQuery triggered keyup event get lost?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1

My `keyup` handler works fine, even though the setup is a little complicated.  This is happening in an iframe overlay.  The main page does

```js
our.Catalog.makeViewer = function(id) {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.setAttribute()... // src, id, name, etc.  Exact same host and method
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.contentWindow.focus();
  $('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}
our.Catalog.makeViewer('foo') // actually bound to a click hander
```

In the iframe `<head>` we have something like

```js
our.Viewer = function(){
   $(document).keyup(function(e){ doSomething() })
   // and lots more, of course
}
$(function() {
  new our.Viewer();
});
```

The browser displays the URL of the iframe.  I get all the real keyups for the whole browser window which is fine, but for testing I want to be able to simulate keyups from JavaScript.  However, whatever I try doesn't work. I've tried

```js
$('body').trigger($.Event('keyup', {keycode: 40}))
$(document).trigger($.Event('keyup', {keycode: 40})) 
$(document).keyup()
```

and none of them triggered my handler.  Then I thought maybe the problem was that I'm using iframes, so I tried

```js
$('#frameId').contents().find('body').trigger($.Event('keyup', {keycode: 40}))
```

Nope, that doesn't work either.  I don't think it's any kind of permissions/security issue because `$('#frameId').contents().find('body').addClass('test')` works fine.

I hope I'm doing something stupid someone can easily correct.  How can I simulate keyups from my JavaScript driver?

Comment: I'm a little confused on your whole HTML setup. Where are you binding the `keyup` handler? In the parent page or in the iframe? Events won't bubble out of an iframe, so you can't trigger an event **in** the iframe and expect to catch them in the parent page.

Comment: @Ian he suggested he was using `<frame>` not `<iframe>`.

Comment: seem to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/Exuh4/1/

Comment: is the `keyup` event registered in the main document or within the iframe

Comment: @DerFlatulator How do you know that? They said "that I'm using frames". That's a general term, so neither of us are right because they didn't specify. Either way, I'm pretty sure events aren't bubbled up from any **frames**

Comment: @Ian My previous comment may have given the wrong impression. I just interpreted "I'm using frames" as "I'm using `<frame>s`".

Comment: @DerFlatulator Right, and for some reason I interpreted it as "I'm using `<frames>`s". Either way, my point is that events don't bubble from any type of frames, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Sorry @Ian, I should have been clearer. I'm using iframes and have updated the question with more details.

Comment: @OldPro No problem, thanks for explaining and providing more info. So I'm wondering if it's something weird with how jQuery triggers "events", across frames. I doubt it will fix it, but try `var iframeWindow = $('#frameId').contents(); iframeWindow.find('body').trigger(iframeWindow.$.Event('keyup', {keycode: 40}))`

Comment: @Ian, nope, `iframeWIndow.$` is undefined.

Comment: @OldPro Yeah, I think I was wrong with that. Hold on :)

Comment: How about: `var iframe = $("#frameId"); iframe.contents().find("body").trigger((iframe.contentWindow || iframe).$.Event("keyup", {keycode: 40}));`

Comment: @Ian, nope, iframe.contentWindow doesn't help either.

Comment: **CRAP**. Sorry, I typed it wrong. How about: `var iframe = $("#frameId"); iframe.contents().find("body").trigger((iframe[0].contentWindow || iframe[0]).$.Event("keyup", {keycode: 40}));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the [code recommended by the jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) docs works from Selenium.  Or at least the one-liner version:

```
$('body').trigger($.Event('keyup', {keycode: 40, which: 40}))
```

In my particular case I wasn't seeing it from Selenium because our handler checks `e.which` not `e.keycode` and `e.which` remained undefined until we set it explicitly.  Maybe a bug in jQuery 1.7.1?  Maybe due to an interaction between jQuery and Selenium?  Anyway, setting `e.which` got the test passing.

On the other hand, getting stuff to work from a browser console was more challenging.  From Firebug on Firefox I had to `cd(frames[2])` to set the context to the `iframe` in question.  No other way of accessing the iframe from another frame would let me trigger events, probably due to some kind of sandboxing. (I can access the iframe's DOM but not the iframe's jQuery.)  In Chrome I have to select the iframe from the popup menu at the bottom of the console. In Safari I have to use

```
window.frames[2].$('body').trigger($.Event('keyup', {keycode: 40, which: 40}))
```

So as I expected, something relatively stupid, not setting the iframe context in the console and actually failing the test in Selenium for other reasons.

Thank you @Ian for trying.

Answer (score -2):

try tihis

```
$(document).on("keyUp",function(){ 
    //your logic
});
```

Answer (score -2):

[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)  only works with events binded with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Try binding with:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
    doSomething(e.keyCode);
});
```

And testing with:

```
$(document).trigger($.Event("keyup", { keyCode: 40 }));
```

Comment: The `.keyUp` method is just a shortcut for `.on("keyup");`. And `.trigger()` works with any "form" of event handling in jQuery - as long as you bind the events with jQuery

Comment: It may be a shortcut, but I tested my code in a console and it did work.